# Memory Leaks in UIPickerView using sqlite

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, sqlite

I'm adding self.notes array to a UIPickerView. This is how I'm setting the array:

```
 NSMutableArray *notesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [notesArray addObject:@"-"];
 [notesArray addObjectsFromArray:[dbManager getTableValues:@"Notes"]];
 self.notes = notesArray;
 [notesArray release];
```

The info for the UIPickerView is taken from the database in this method:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getTableValues:(NSString *)table
{
  NSMutableArray *valuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  if (sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK)
  {
      sqlite3_close(database);
      NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
  }
  else 
  {
   NSString *query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT value FROM %@", table];
   sqlite3_stmt *statement;

   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
     while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
     NSString *value =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
     [valuesArray addObject:value];
     [value release]; 
   }
   sqlite3_reset(statement);
  }
  [query release]; 
  sqlite3_finalize(statement);
  sqlite3_close(database);
 }
 return valuesArray;
}
```

But I keep getting memory leaks in Instruments for these lines:

NSMutableArray *valuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

and

[valuesArray addObject:value];

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `NSMutableArray *valuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` use this line:

```
NSMutableArray *valuesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

As for the `[valuesArray addObject:value];` leak, change your code to this:

```
[valuesArray addObject:value];
value = nil;
```

Comment: value should not be released here, as it is not alloced. It is leaking as the container valuesArray is leaking.

Comment: Thanks! All my leaks are gone

Answer (score 0):

You are returning valuesArray from the getTableValues which is allocated but not released. You can not release it in the method as the caller still needs it. The correct way is to autorelease it.

```
return [valuesArray autorelease];
```

And also you don't need to release value string after adding it to valuesArray as it is created with a convenient constructor.